# Find the general solution of non homogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find the general solution of the following non homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficient:
$$a_n − 11a_{n−1} + 30a_{n−2}= n^2(5^n)$$
I tried the homogeneous part. $a_n−11a_{n−1}+30a_{n−2}=0$ and i get C=5 and D=6
I need full solution

Answer (score 1):

First we solve the homogeneous part:
$$A_n-11A_{n-1}+30 A_{n-2}=0~~~~(1),$$ we let $A_n=x^n$ and get $X_1,x_2=6.$ So the solution of (1) is $A_n=C_1 5^n+ C_2 6^n~~~~(2)$
Next, for $$A_n-11A_{n-1}+30 A_{n-2}=n^2 5^n~~~~(2),$$ we let $A_n=(an^3+bn^2+cn+d)5^n$ in (2), Comparing the co-efficients of various powers of $n$, we get $a=-5/3, b=-65/2, c=-2165/6.$
Sothe total solution of (2) is:
$$A_n=C_1 5^n+ C_2 6^n+[-(5/3)n^3-(65/2)n^2-(2165/6)n+d)]~5^n,$$
the undetermined $d$ can be combined with $C_1$.

Comment: Thanks Dr Zadar Ahmed DSc

Comment: @happy, welcome so now you may accept the answer.

Comment: you sure about the answer 100% coz I m going to submit to my teacher

Comment: Ye, you can check various steps here.

Comment: Ok thanks good luck

Comment: check this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517057/discrete-mathematics-graph-theory-problem?noredirect=1#comment7233213_3517057